# Was Og responsible to follow the commandments for B'nei Noach?

Tags: gentiles, midrash, mabul, noachide-laws

The Midrash relates that Og, later to become King of Bashan, survived the flood in the generation of Noach ([Pirkei d'Rabbi Eliezer, 23](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=21858&pgnum=137)). Was he responsible for following the seven commandments despite not being a member of Noach's family?

**Edit:**

As DoubleAA wrote in the [comments below](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16836/was-og-responsible-to-follow-the-commandments-for-bnei-noach#comment36656_16839), I am asking whether the change to Noachide law applied to Og, or whether he was bound by the previous code.

Answer (score 9):

We call them the "sheva mitzvos bnei Noach," but I think that the term is "lav davka" (imprecise).

See [Rambam, Melachim 9:1](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=14&hilchos=83&perek=9&hilite=). From his language, it seems that Og was obligated in all seven except ever min hachai. But see [the Kesef Mishneh there](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?mfid=90441&rid=14990) ('ד"ה על ששה דברים כו); from his language it seems that Og was either not allowed to eat meat *at all* or was also obligated in ever min hachai, since before Noach meat was not permitted at all.

Comment: I think the question was if, after the flood, Og became obligated in 7 or remained only obligated in 6.

Comment: Yes, and if he remained obligated in only six, he couldn't eat meat at all, as I explained using the K"M.

Comment: That's fine. It still doesn't answer which of those two situations he was in.

Comment: ba - I've clarified my question as per @DoubleAA

Comment: Also worth mentioning the opinion of Tosafos ([*Sanhedrin* 56b](https://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=24&daf=56b&format=text), s.v. *Achol*) that Adam was prohibited from killing and eating meat but was permitted to eat meat from animals that died *sua sponte*.